# Python: alternate for stdin() when running headless?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, stdin

I am passing data from hcitool and hcidump, via sed and awk then piped into python, which then reads from stdin.  This works well when run from the command line.  It works equally well when put into a shell program and called from the command line.

However, when I call that shell program via cron on startup and run headless, the python program executes, but nothing ever flows from sed | awk into python.

I have read thin wisps of information that stdin may not flow thru headless, but haven't found anything concrete.

What am I missing?

Comment: instead of piping you could use `subprocess.call` with `shell=True`. or something similar. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: The pipe `|` is a function of the shell, so ensure you have a shell running before you execute those scripts. Also, _when I call that shell program via cron on startup and run headless_ - this really doesn't make any sense. You don't "call cron on startup" (its called automatically at an interval) and "run headless" only applies if you have X windows or some other graphical interface running (which has no bearing on `stdin`).

Comment: actually, cron can execute a command at startup via @reboot, so that part is OK.  "Headless" in this case refers to the fact that the device (an RPi) is running without a monitor, keyboard, and without a remote session.  I admit I may be using the wrong term here, but I'm not sure how else to describe it.

thank you for the pipe info.  I'll look at the info per the previous commenter.